# Haskell: Retrieve nth value from type which is a tuple

Tags: haskell

I am trying to access some data inside a type from an imported package.

The type is declared (by the package authors) as so:

```
newtype MultiBalanceReport =
  MultiBalanceReport ([DateSpan]
                     ,[MultiBalanceReportRow]
                     ,MultiBalanceReportTotals
                     )
```

And I'm trying to extract the first list in the type with a function like so:

```
getDates :: MultiBalanceReport -> [DateSpan]
getDates (date,_,_) = date
```

But when I use the function, the compiler complains that the types aren't the same:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘MultiBalanceReport’
              with actual type ‘([DateSpan], t7, t8)’
```

I feel like the compiler just doesn't know the inner details of the `MultiBalanceReport` type? Am I not importing the package which defines the type correctly?

I'm new to Haskell, so sorry if I'm using the wrong nomenclature to try to describe my problem.

Comment: I'd consider that to be an antipattern. Just use a `data MBR = MBR [DateSpan] [MultiBalanceReportRow] MultiBalanceReportTotals` and avoid the tupling, using only the `MBR` constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `newtype` is a data type **with a constructor**, so you need to **unwrap** the tuple out of the constructor `MultiBalanceReport` first:

```
getDates :: MultiBalanceReport -> [DateSpan]
getDates (MultiBalanceReport (date,_,_)) = date
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to include the newtype in your pattern match

```
getDates :: MultiBalanceReport -> [DateSpan]
getDates (MultiBalanceReport (date,_,_)) = date
```

Answer (score 3):

You're really close. You're pattern matching on a tuple type, but the actual value you have is a `MultiBalanceReport` which *contains* a tuple.

```
getDates :: MultiBalanceReport -> [DateSpan]
getDates (MultiBalanceReport (date,_,_)) = date
```